# exact match of a given number of characters in a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

I have an array of strings:

```
strings = ['fo','foo','fooo']
```

What code should I write in order to find a string that has only `oo` in it?

I tried following code

```
strings.select!{|string| string.include? 'oo'}
#=> ['foo','fooo']
```

However, `'fooo'` is not what I wanted in a resulting array, in this case only an array with `['foo']` should be returned.

Comment: You're wrong. `"foo"` includes not only `"oo"`, but also `"f"`, `"fo"`, `"foo"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
strings.select { |s| s.count('o') == 2 && /o{2}/ =~ s }
```

**Edit:**
Edited for correctness based on comments.

Comment: This solution will select `photo` if present in `strings` array.  Is that desirable?

Comment: Since this rejects "oofoo", I assume you've assumed that only one "oo" can appear in the string.

Answer (score 1):

> what code should I write in order to find a string that has only `oo` in it?

```
strings.select{|e| e == "oo"}
```

Comment: I am sorry, a string should include 'oo'

Comment: Nadir, sawa has interpreted your question literally, namely, that you want to find a string that *only* contains `"oo"`, which is another way of saying you want to find *the* string `"oo"`. That's clearly not what you want, but it's the only way your question can be interpreted. For example, does `"foodooo"` satisfiy your requirement? You need to edit your question to state it more precisely. You should do that even though you selected an answer, as many others may read it in future. Don't change your question, just add to it, indicating it's an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this.

```
strings = ['fo','foo','fooo', 'oofo', 'oofoo', 'oof', 'photo', 'photoo', "hi"]

s = strings.select do |s| 
    s.chars.each_cons(2).map(&:join).count("oo") == 1
end
#=> ["foo", "oofo", "oof", "photoo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether a string contains one or more strings of the form "xooy", where "x" and "y" are any characters other than "o", but contains no strings "xoy" and or "ooo" (and by extension, no "oooo", etc.), you could do the following:

```
def double_os_only?(str)
  str.scan(/o+/).map(&:size).minmax == [2,2]
end

strings = ['fo','foo','fooo', 'oofo', 'oofoo', 'oofooo', 'photo', 'potatoo', "dang"]
strings.map { |s| puts "#{ s } => #{ double_os_only?(s) }" }

fo      => false
foo     => true
fooo    => false
oofo    => false
oofoo   => true
oofooo  => false
photo   => false
potatoo => false
dang    => false
```

Note that, if `str.scan(/o+/) #=> []`, `[].map(&:size) #=> []` and `[].minmax #=> [nil,nil]`.

Another way is to modify a regex given by @Avinash:

```
R = /
    ^             # match beginning of the line
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      [^o]*       # match zero or more characters other than 'o'
      oo          # match 'oo'
      [^o]*       # match zero or more characters other than 'o'
      (?!o)       # do not match 'o' in a negative lookahead
    )+            # end the non-capture group and perform >= 1 times
    $             # match end of line
    /x            # extended/free-spacing regex definition

def double_os_only?(str)
  !!(str =~ R)
end
```

`!` converts a truthy value to `false` and a falsy value to `true`. `!!` therefore converts a truthy value to `true` and a falsy value to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookarounds..

```
> strings.select{ |i| i[/(?<!o)oo(?!o)/] }
=> ["foo"]
```

`(?<!o)` asserts that the match won't be preceded by `o`, `(?!o)` asserts that the match won't be followed by `o`

To match the string which contain exactly 2 o's

```
strings.select{ |i| i[/^[^o]*oo[^o]*$/] }
```

Comment: Your code will select `"oofooo"`. Is that expected?

Comment: don't know, may be op knows.

Comment: You should have a clear opinion before answering any thing.

Comment: @sawa then why you answered this question? You also should have a clear opinion before answering... Many questions on SO are similar to this, no one read the op's mind. From his question, what I undersatnd is, he wants to match all the elements in an array where exactly two `oo` appears anywhere on that string.

Comment: Yes. I have a clear opinion, although it is not the same as yours. I answered it according to what the OP asked. I thought that you answered it under your interpretation, but you do not seem to be clear.

Comment: I have never particularly paid special attention to you. I judge a post by its content.